# How can I fix sympy/symbolic package error?

Tags: python, pip, sympy, octave, symbolic-math

I already installed python3 and sympy on my Mac, but when using octave I get this error:

```
pkg load symbolic
syms x y real
Symbolic pkg v3.0.1: Traceback (most recent call last):
File “”, line 1, in
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘sympy’
error: Python cannot import SymPy: have you installed SymPy?
Try “sympref diagnose” for more information.
error: called from
assert_have_python_and_sympy at line 135 column 7
python_ipc_popen2 at line 85 column 5
python_ipc_driver at line 62 column 15
pycall_sympy__ at line 164 column 11
valid_sym_assumptions at line 38 column 10
assumptions at line 82 column 7
syms at line 140 column 13
```

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Make sure that the interpreter you installed sympy to is the same interpreter as the one Octave is using

Comment: and that it has `sympy` installed.